# Type the max number title in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, attributes, max

I want two fill land type with column a , b , c , d. If A is greater then all 3 then type A or if b is greater then A, C and D then type B or if c is greater then A, B and D then Type C or if D is greater then A, B, C then type D in one cell in Excel.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2BPI.jpg)

```
CCA         Banjar_Kadeem   Ghasni      Gair_Mumkin Land_Type
0.112       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.018       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.177       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.243       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.033       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.056       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.045       0.000           0.000       0.003       CCA
0.064       0.064           0.000       0.000       Banjar_Kadeem
0.127       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.040       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.059       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.031       0.000           0.000       0.004       CCA
0.000       0.000           0.000       0.005       Gair_Mumkin
0.000       0.000           0.000       0.009       Gair_Mumkin
0.000       0.000           0.000       0.069       Gair_Mumkin
0.167       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.000       0.000           0.000       0.007       Gair_Mumkin
0.000       0.000           0.000       0.019       Gair_Mumkin
0.014       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.046       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.040       0.000           0.000       0.000       CCA
0.048       0.048           0.000       0.000       Banjar_Kadeem
```

Comment: You are effectively looking to sort the headers by row of descending data. What about situations of a tie? First value is the 'winner'?

Comment: Are these two separate situations? because they read the same, or have you just duplicated the text?

Comment: Sidenote, if you would want help, consider to post the data as markdown table instead for other to copy over the data and work on a solution.

Comment: @JvdV not possible.. all values are different. Pls check image

Comment: CCA Banjar_Kadeem Ghasni Gair_Mumkin Land_Type
0.112 0.000 0.000 0.000 CCA
0.018 0.000 0.000 0.000 CCA
0.177 0.000 0.000 0.000 CCA
0.243 0.000 0.000 0.000 CCA
0.033 0.000 0.000 0.000 CCA
0.056 0.000 0.000 0.000 CCA
0.045 0.000 0.000 0.003 CCA
0.064 0.064 0.000 0.000 Banjar_Kadeem
0.127 0.000 0.000 0.000 CCA
0.040 0.000 0.000 0.000 CCA
0.059 0.000 0.000 0.000 CCA
0.031 0.000 0.000 0.004 CCA
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.005 Gair_Mumkin

Comment: I HAVE FOUR COULEMS. IN WHICH ONE COULEM IS GREATER THEN OTHER THREE COULEM. SO I WANT TO WRITE THE TITLE NAME IN 5TH COULEM.

Comment: Please do not shout and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75904690/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Comment: @NeelStar it is off-topic, but you should nt right in `CAPITAL` or `BLOCK` letters as it means you are shouting to those whom you are replying, instead if you want to highlight some context then click on help and use the requisite formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indicated all the columns are different, but your sample data has two columns the same.

I assume that the data is incorrect.

This formula will do what you want.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$1,MATCH(MAX(A2:D2),A2:D2,0))
```

Place in E2 and drag down

Answer (score 1):

If you have duplicates and want to list all you could use:

`=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER($A$1:$D$1,A2:D2=MAX(A2:D2),""))`

Or as commented by Mayukh Bhattacharya:
`=ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER($A$1:$D$1,A2:D2=MAX(A2:D2),""))`

Comment: Nice, I see it automatically adds the comma separator if applicable and ignoring blanks. Did not use it before, but it's very nice in this case.

Comment: Nah @P.b it ignores the blanks because of `FILTER()` function, is doesn't have the parameter like `TEXTJOIN()` but in this post it will work, I hope so. Afaik, OP needs the header based on MAX values, so I dont think there will be any value without any header.

Comment: Gotcha. And yes, it would be 1 to 4 values that equal the max value of the referenced cells.